# Reboot Win10 into different boot configuration remotely

Tags: boot, windows-10, remote-access, bcdedit

Via `bcdedit` I've configured an additional boot config for Windows 10 (has Hyper-V disabled). I know I can switch between the normal config and my new config using the boot options menu locally, but I'd also like to do it remotely too via the command line for example.

Is there an easy way to do this? I can't find an option on the `shutdown` command. The only other way I can think is to use `bcdedit /default` to set the configuration I want then `shutdown -r`, but ideally I don't want to change the default.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could use bcdedit to set UEFI "bootnext" variable.

The parameter is a loader GUID which has to be used after reboot.
The loader can be any Windows loader (or a Linux loader) - in your case you want to switch two Windows loaders (one with and one without Hyper-V).

See [short description of UEFI NVRAM variables accessible from Windows 10/8/7](http://windows7boot.blogspot.bg/2014/05/exploring-windows-uefi-part-1.html).